# C++ pure virtual void

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, syntax-error

I have been reading about polymorphism and decided to create a program. In the base class, I have made it abstract so the derive classes would be able to use it without error. But when I try to give derive class an object it says that

> 2 IntelliSense: object of abstract class type "Son" is not allowed:
>             line:38

anyway here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Father{
protected:
    string prof;
    string name;
public:
    virtual void getProf_getName() = 0; //pure virtual function
    virtual void showProf_showName() = 0; //pure virtual function
};

class Son: public Father{
public:
    Son(){} //creating constructor
    void getProf_getName(string hName, string hProf){
    name = hName;
    prof = hProf;
    }
    void showProf_showName(){
        cout << "The son name is " << name << " and he is a " << prof << endl;
    }
    ~Son(){cout << "Deleting Son" << endl;} // deleting memory
};


int main(){
    //local variables
    string name;
    string profession;
    //User interface
    cout << "What is the name of the son: ";
    getline(cin,name);
    cout << "What is his profession: ";
    getline(cin,profession);
    //implementing data
    Son son; // Error       error C2259: 'Son' : cannot instantiate abstract class      line:38 column:1

    son.getProf_getName(name,profession);
    son.showProf_showName();
    //showing info 
    son.showProf_showName();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `getProf_getName(string hName, string hProf)` is a different function than `getProf_getName()`, so the `Son` class is still abstract since there's no concrete implementation of `getProf_getName()`.

Comment: As a side comment, always use virtual destructors when using polymorphism.

Comment: As another side comment, is the Son really a Father? :)

Comment: @JBL i think that's 'is-a, but don't tell anyone'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have one problem. See the following declaration:

```
virtual void getProf_getName() = 0;
```

You reimplemented `getProf_getName()` with the signature

```
void getProf_getName(string hName, string hProf);
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                      different parameters
```

These **aren't the same functions**, you're not reimplementing the virtual, so naturally the compiler complains that he doesn't find any implementation of the pure virtual you declared in the base class.

As for the error message: as you didn't reimplemented *all* virtual functions, `Son` is then an abstract class itself.

Comment: Just as a side note, if you've got a c++11 compiler then it's a good idea to add the `override` specifier to prevent these issues slipping through (i.e when base class isn't abstract).

Answer (score 0):

Your signature is different

```
    virtual void getProf_getName(string hName, string hProf) = 0; //pure virtual function
```